# APINotFoundError: invalid media id

Tags: instagram-api

I want to get information using the media endpoint from Instagram. I don't know what is going on when I request this particularly endpoint https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/BIU_L3sg_9P?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN. This shortcode Im sure that exists.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you include the code you are using to perform this API call?

Comment: are u in sandbox mode? is that your photo?

Comment: I've pasted the url in the url field on Chrome Browser. This is not my photo, Im just trying to get comments from a post. And Im not using sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where did u get that shortcode from?

I looked up the user and that photo from  instagram, here is the same photo with different shortcode `BH2XfKpB4br` from instagram, this works:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/BH2XfKpB4br?access_token=XXX

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what happened. A user has attached this shortcode in our platform, then we used this code to get media information from Instagram. We change to this new shortcode that you pasted, and it worked!

Comment: the old one is also valid, but on works on instagram website, not with API http://instagram.com/p/BIU_L3sg_9P, i opened this URL, click on user and click on the same photo, it had different shortcode, this works with API